# Ayuda de filtros con switch html y php

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

hola tengo una duda estoy trabajando con dompdf y quiero que se cargue una plantila para cada marca de pc que hay pero al hacerlo no me carga las varibles que cargo en el dompdf adjunto el codigo que llama al pdf

```html
<a href="pdf.php?orden=<?php echo $orden?>&Nombre=<?=$Nombre?>&Marca=<?=$Marca?>&Equipo=<?=$Equipo?>&Serial=<?=$Serial?>&Cargo=<?=$Cargo?>&Cedula=<?=$Cedula?>&Celular=<?=$Celular?>" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">Descargar-PDF</i></a>
```

lo intente con un switch pero no me carga las variables el pdf[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque la imagen que proporcionas, no corresponde exactamente al código que muestras, creo que el problema se debe al uso de los short tags de php, quizás estén deshabilitados a nivel de servidor.

Prueba con esto para descartar esa opción:

```
<a href="pdf.php?orden=<?php echo $orden?>&Nombre=a<?php echo $Nombre?>&Marca=<?php echo $Marca?>&Equipo=<?php echo $Equipo?>&Serial=<?php echo $Serial?>&Cargo=<?php echo $Cargo?>&Cedula=<?php echo $Cedula?>&Celular=<?php echo $Celular?>" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">Descargar-PDF</i></a>
```

Nos cuentas como te fue. Saludos,

Comment: no que pena talvez me hice entender mal el href que subi es como esta bien y la imagen fue el intento que hice con un switch pero no funciono, asi como esta esta bien necesito es ayuda para filtrarlo y mostrar un formato u otro dependiendo de la "marca"